# Sign in with LinkedIn - button not showing

Tags: javascript

We used  "Sign in with LinkedIn"  for my client's website.  This has worked well.  But now the button does not show on Internet Explorer (I am using IE9).  But the button appears on Chrome?

We are using Umbraco as the CMS but I am not sure this has anything to do with the problem.

When I 'View Source' in IE, I can see all the javascript but the button is just not displaying.

I am going bonkers... all ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn no longer supports IE9 as stated in their official support list:
https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4135/~/supported-internet-browsers

At the very least refactor your code for newer versions of IE. Paste your snippet or URL and we can see what may be remedied.